# How to perform distinct average in Pandas Groupby in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this:

**Input**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df.head(8)
date          id       count
01.02.2020    a        5
01.02.2020    b        10
02.02.2020    a        6
02.02.2020    b        11
03.02.2020    a        9
03.02.2020    a        13
03.02.2020    b        3
03.02.2020    b        5
...
```

**Desired Output**

```
date          distinctAverage
01.02.2020    7.5
02.02.2020    8.5
03.02.2020    15         # (9+13+3+5)/2, because 2 distinct entries out of 4 entries
...
```

**Function**

I want to compute the unique average of `"count"` for unique IDs in a groupby expression.
I group the data like this:

```
df.groupby(
    ["date"]
    ).agg(
        #sumCount=("count", "sum"), # works!
        #countUniqueIDs=("id", lambda x: x.nunique()),  # works!
        distinctAverage=("count", lambda x, y=df["id"]: x.sum() / y.nunique()), # Doesn't work!
        distinctAverage2=("count", "mean") # Doesn't work, takes 4 as the denominator at 03.02.2020
    ).reset_index()
```

Any idea on how to accomplish a distinct average?

EDIT: Answer: The distinctAverage as mentioned above works just fine for the sample data. In a bigger dataset that can't be displayed here it doesn't work (for whatever reason!), and there is a workaround:
After using the groupby and aggregating `"sumCount"` and `"countUniqueIDs"`, add another line after the groupby: `df["workaroundDistinctAverage"] = df["sumCount"] / df["countUniqueIDs"]`
Not very elegant, but easier to understand than accepted answer.

Comment: Did an answer solve your problem? If yes, please mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/694919)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the `.groupby()` return in a variable and then compute what you need with `.sum()` and `.nunique()`

```
grouper = df.groupby(['date'])

(
  (grouper['count'].sum() / grouper['id'].nunique())
  .reset_index(name = 'distinctAverage')
)
#output:
    date        distinctAverage
0   01.02.2020  7.5
1   02.02.2020  8.5
2   03.02.2020  15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine !

```
df.groupby(["date"]).agg(
        distinctAverage=("count", lambda x, y=df["id"]: float(x.sum()/ y.nunique()))
        )
```